# PHP Accessing a file that has been locked for editing - Permission Denied error

Tags: php, flock, locked-files

I'm doing some csv parsing, and if I cancel the parsing (by navigating to a different page or refreshing) before the fclose() function gets called, I get the below error when I go back and start up the program again:

```
Warning: unlink(spreadsheet.csv) [function.unlink]: Permission denied
```

When I try to open the spreadsheet.csv file in excel, I get a "File in Use" error, saying "spreadsheet.csv is locked for editing by 'another user.'" I understand that my php server is currently stuck in a state of trying to access the file. Is there a way I can use php to check  if the file is locked for editing, and unlock it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to unlock a file with php like this:

```
$rFile = fopen("path/file.txt", "r+");
flock($rFile, LOCK_UN); 
fclose($rFile);
```

And the best way to get read-write access to the file is this:

```
$iOldumask = umask(0);
chmod("path/file.txt", 0777);
umask($iOldumask);
```

Comment: good advice, but I figured out my problem. My web page uses an ajax call to return data from a very long php script, so even if I exit the page early, that php script is still being carried out. Is there a way I could tell the server to stop trying to execute the previous ajax request, if there still is one running in the background?

Comment: Yes, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [flock()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php).

I use it like:

```
if (!$file->flock(LOCK_EX)) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to obtain lock on file');
}
```